# Is there a parameter to avoid double URL encoding in WSO2 api manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I type a "é" in API>Design>General Details>Description, it is displayed as "&eacute;" (in HTML source code : "`&amp;eacute;`") in the store.

Is there a parameter to set somewhere to avoid this double encoding ?

EDIT : if it's a bug where could I create an issue ?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, it shows the correct character in publisher. You can report the bug in https://wso2.org/jira/projects/APIMANAGER

Comment: Well in publisher it's an editable Textarea, while in store, it's just plain HTML text. Can you create the issue for me please ? I don't have any account.

Comment: in publisher once published ,in overview page it appears correctly . You can register here and create jiras https://wso2.com/user/register

Comment: Ok, thanks. I had an account already, didn't know it was working for JIRA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been created on JIRA : https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5525